# How to create an array of dispatch_block_t in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, grand-central-dispatch

I have a code in Swift 1.2 to create an array of dispatch_block_t and it works fine. But the same code throws error in Swift 2.0.

```
var menuView: btSimplePopUP!

let actions: [dispatch_block_t] = [{self.pickImages()},
    {self.takePicture()},
    {self.pickVideos()},
    {self.shootVideo()},
    {self.recordAudio()},
    {self.closeView()}]

menuView = btSimplePopUP(itemImage: imgs as [AnyObject],
    andTitles: titles as [AnyObject],
    andActionArray:  actions as NSArray as [AnyObject],
    addToViewController: self)
```

The above code works fine in Swift 1.2. But in Swift 2.0, it throws the following error

> [dispatch_block_t] is not convertible to NSArray

How can I create an NSArray with dispatch_block_t?

**UPDATE:**

I have replaced the above code with the following one,

```
let actions: [Any] = [{self.pickImages()},
                    {self.takePicture()},
                    {self.pickVideos()},
                    {self.shootVideo()},
                    {self.recordAudio()},
                    {self.closeView()}]

menuView = btSimplePopUP(itemImage: imgs as [AnyObject],
        andTitles: titles as [AnyObject],
        andActionArray:  actions as! [AnyObject],
        addToViewController: self)
```

Now, the previous error is gone. But I am getting the following error in run time,

> fatal error: array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = false

import Foundation

let a: dispatch_block_t = {
    print("a")
}
let b: dispatch_block_t = {
    print("b")
}
let arr = [a,b]
print(arr.dynamicType)
arr.forEach { (b) -> () in
    b()
}
/* prints
Array<@convention(block) () -> ()>
a
b
*/
class Block {
    var block: dispatch_block_t
    init(block: dispatch_block_t){
        self.block = block
    }
}
let block1 = Block(block: a)
let block2 = Block(block: b)

let arr2: NSArray = [block1,block2]
print(arr2)
arr2.forEach { (p) -> () in
    (p as? Block)?.block()
}
/* prints
(
    Block,
    Block
)
a
b
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to pass this array as a NSArray to a function. While passing, I am getting this error, "[dispatch_block_t] is not convertible to NSarray". Any idea to pass this as NSArray?

Comment: NSArray can not hold value types. For that you need to box the dispatch_block_t. see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you @user3441734 Now, I could convert that to NSArray. But I am getting the following error in the function definition, `*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7a5841b0 of class 'ProjName.Block' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[ProjName.Block copy]`

Comment: The function definition is,  `- (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image title:(NSString *)title action:(dispatch_block_t)action {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _title = [title copy];
        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
        _action = [action copy];
    }
    
    return self;
}`

Comment: aha ... so now it is totally new question :-). i am going to check the source code of you objc code ...

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch_block_t` is not inherited from AnyObject, it's not object.
But you can modify your code and change `AnyObject` to `Any` like this:

```
andActionArray : actions as [Any]
```

And it should work for you.

UPD:

Your function takes param as `NSArray`, you can simply cast your array to this type, this code works in my swift playground:

```
func pickImages() {}
func takePicture() {}
func shootVideo() {}

let actions: [dispatch_block_t] = [{pickImages()},
    {takePicture()},
    {shootVideo()}]
var actionArray: NSArray = actions as NSArray // pass it to the btSimplePopUP init
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.. But now I am getting the following error      "[dispatch_block_t] is not convertible to [Any]"

Comment: show your `btSimplePopUP` init function? What type is for `andActionArray` there? I can't help you more without your code

Comment: btSimplePopUp is an open source, that I have used to display a menu. The link for the init function is https://github.com/balram3429/btSimplePopUp/blob/master/btSimplePopUp/btSimplePopUP.m  and the init function starts at Line: 284

Comment: I could not cast it to NSArray. I am getting this error, "[dispatch_block_t] is not convertible to NSarray"

Comment: pls do see my updated question. I've changed the type of actions to [Any] and i dint get any compile time errors. But in run time, I am getting "fatal error: array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C"

Comment: @Deepica Masilamani dispatch_block_t is NOT func. see my answer

Comment: @user3441734 i dint use dispatch_block_t as a function. I am trying to create an array that has dispatch_block_t as elements and I need to pass this as an NSArray to another function.