# How to implement copyWithZone in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2, nscopying

The following code is written in Swift 2.0 to create an array of `dispatch_block_t`

```
let a: dispatch_block_t = {
    self.pickImages()
}
let b: dispatch_block_t = {
    self.takePicture()
}
let c: dispatch_block_t = {
    self.pickVideos()
}
let d: dispatch_block_t = {
    self.shootVideo()
}
let e: dispatch_block_t = {
    self.recordAudio()
}
let f: dispatch_block_t = {
    self.closeView()
}

let block1 = Block(block: a)
let block2 = Block(block: b)
let block3 = Block(block: c)
let block4 = Block(block: d)
let block5 = Block(block: e)
let block6 = Block(block: f)

let actionsArray: NSArray = [block1, block2, block3, block4, block5, block6]
```

And the `Block` class is defined as follows,

```
class Block: NSObject, NSCopying {
    var block: dispatch_block_t

    init(block: dispatch_block_t){
        self.block = block
    }

    func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        return self.block as! AnyObject
    }
}
```

I could create an array of dispatch_block_t with the above piece of code. But, I need to pass this array as a parameter to another function and I am facing an issue in passing this array.

I am calling this function on a button click event,

```
menuView = btSimplePopUP(itemImage: imgs as [AnyObject],
    andTitles: titles as [AnyObject],
    andActionArray:  actionsArray as [AnyObject],
    addToViewController: self)
```

And I am getting an error when the following snippet is executed,

```
- (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image title:(NSString *)title action:(dispatch_block_t)action {
if ((self = [super init])) {
    _title = [title copy];
    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    _action = [action copy];
}

return self;
}
```

And the error is,

> Could not cast value of type '() -> ()' (0x15164018) to 'Swift.AnyObject' (0x101e500c).

I am getting this error in `copyWithZone` function of `Block` class.

The complete source code for btSimplePopUp can be viewed here, 
https://github.com/balram3429/btSimplePopUp/blob/master/btSimplePopUp/btSimplePopUP.m

Comment: you asked the same question in third time, what the error u faced if conversion or type cast

Comment: Previously, I could not create an array of dispatch_block_t. But now, I have created the array. But I could not process it in the function defined in another class.

Comment: `*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7a5841b0 of class 'ProjName.Block' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead Unrecognized selector -[ProjName.Block copy]` I received this error before defining the `copyWithZone` function in `Block` class. After defining it, I am getting the following error, `Could not cast value of type '() -> ()' (0x15164018) to 'Swift.AnyObject' (0x101e500c).` . Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: your eroor says you cant cast to any type so is not in **AnyObject** use in here **NSMutableArray? or NSArray?** for return type

Comment: I have tried changing the return type of `copyWithZone` to `dispatch_block_t` . But I got `Type 'Block' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'` error, since `copyWithZone` is a method of NSCopying.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik pls do check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666143/how-to-create-an-array-of-dispatch-block-t-in-swift-2-0 I just want to convert that code in swift 1.2 to swift 2.0. That's all !!!

Comment: try this var block: dispatch_block_t as NSMutablearray or else self.block = block as NSmutableArray

Comment: I am getting `Cast from 'dispatch_block_t' (aka '() -> ()') to unrelated type 'NSMutableArray' always fails` warning and the app crashes.

Comment: no no I dont know in which type cast are you used for return self.block as! AnyObject ., in here what return type are you added same as add in above initilization also

Comment: Pls do have a look at my question. I have posted the full definitions and the calling methods. I have tried changing the type of block variable to nsmutablearray. But no use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert \[dispatch\_block\_t\] to NSArray in Swift 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672864/how-to-convert-dispatch-block-t-to-nsarray-in-swift-2-0)

Comment: @katleta3000 The link that you have mentioned and this post are different. Please do have a look at this post.

Answer (score 1):

`dispatch_block_t` is a struct, not an object. In fact it's a C struct. I don't understand why you need to use a dispatch_block_t, why not just pass the closure around. If you have to pass it to a `dispatch_` function wrap it in a dispatch_block_t at the call site.

To Swiftify this:

In Swift, `dispatch_block_t` is simply an alias for `() -> ()` i.e. a void function/closure returning `Void`. So you can simply say

```
let a = { self.pickImages() }
// etc

let actionArray = [ a, b, c, ...]
```

However, `pickImages` is a function that has the same type (technically it is curried over `self` but don't worry about what that means) so you can forget about the a, b, c bit and just do this

```
let actionArray = [ self.pickImages, self.takePhoto, ... ]
```

And in Swift, you can use one of the "objects" in that array any time you have a parameter that takes a `dispatch_block_t` e.g.

```
dispatch_after(someTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), actionArray[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am a newbie to iOS. Can you please post some sample code to pass the closure?

Comment: [Apple's documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/) that `dispatch_block_t` is a typedef for `void (^)(void)`. Which means that it **is** an object. (which means that it's also a C struct, but it's not true that it's "not an object".)

Comment: @ParamagneticCroissant It's not an object in the sense that it does not inherit from `AnyObject`. In Swift, there is a fundamental difference between `struct` and `class` and `AnyObject` is ultimately a `class` whereas `() -> ()` is not.

Comment: Thanks for the code and explanation.. I will try it and let you know the result..

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify you Objc framework. your btSimplePopUP should works like ActionContainer from this sample. ActionObject is boxed version of Swift dispatch_block_t. How to unbox it in your code? See ActionContainer job function.

```
//
//  Actions.h
//  test
//


#ifndef Actions_h
#define Actions_h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ActionObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) dispatch_block_t action;
@end


@interface ActionContainer : NSObject
@property  NSArray * actions;
-(void)job;
@end

#endif /* Actions_h */
```

...

```
//
//  Actions.m
//  test
//


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Actions.h"


@implementation ActionObject

-(instancetype)initWithAction: (dispatch_block_t)someaction {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _action = [someaction copy];
    }
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation ActionContainer
-(void)job {
    if (_actions != nil) {
        NSUInteger count = _actions.count;
        NSUInteger i;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ActionObject *action = _actions[i];
            action.action();
        }

    }
}

@end
```

...

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "Actions.h"
```

...

```
//
//  main.swift
//  test
//


import Foundation

let a = ActionObject()
a.action = {
    print("swift a action")
}
let b = ActionObject()
b.action = {
    print("swift b action")
}
let arr: NSArray = [a,b]

let actions = ActionContainer()
actions.actions = arr as [AnyObject]
actions.job()
```

produce

```
swift a action
swift b action
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

...

```
@implementation ActionContainer
-(void)job {
    if (_actions != nil) {
        NSUInteger count = _actions.count;
        NSUInteger i;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ActionObject *action = _actions[i];
            // myAction is 'unboxed' swift block
            // you can save it, run it
            // somwhere in you ObjectiveC code
            dispatch_block_t myAction = action.action;
            // run it
            myAction();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Deepica Masilamani if you still don't have an idea how to modify you own code, publish your whole project on github, i can try modify it for you. it is not necessary to ask the same question again and again. there is no chance to cast swift dispatch_block_t as an AnyObject.

Comment: I will try to make it work, if I can't, i will publish my project in git. Thanks for your help @user3441734

Comment: action.action() just run it (to demonstrate its functionality). the value is action.action. you can save it for further use in action property of btPopUpItem